# How to define a component inside another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react to anyone can help me out to make sure to define a component inside another component in react

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Happy to undo the downvote if you can clarify. For instance, do you just want to write two components in the same file? Do you want to write a functional component into the render function of another? What conditions would count as success?

Answer (score 3):

```
const ComponentTwo =  ()=> <div>I'm a second component.</div>; 

const ComponentOne =  ({children})=> <div>{children}</div>;   


const App = () => (
       <ComponentOne>
          <ComponentTwo />
       </ComponentOne>
      );
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx

Answer (score 0):

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios/index'

const Course = (props)=>(

<tr>
    <td>{props.course.Name}</td>
    <td>{props.course.Course}</td>
    <td>{props.course.PassMark}</td>
    <td>{props.course.LecturerInCharge}</td>
    <td><button className="btn btn-primary" onClick
{()=>CourseView.buttonClick(props.course.Subjects)}>Subject</button></td>
<td><button className="btn btn-primary" onClick=.{()=>CourseView.TotalCalculation(props.course._id)}>Calculate</button></td>
</tr>
);
```

Comment: componentDidMount()
    {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/dropDownData').then(res=>{
            let TeamsFromApi = res.data.map(team=>{return{value:team,display:team}})
            this.setState(
                {
                    teams:[{value:'',display:'(select your favourite team)'}].concat(TeamsFromApi)
                }
            );
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err));

       /* axios.get('http://localhost:4000/sliit/subjects').then(res=>{
            this.setState({subjects:res.data}).catch(err=>console.log(err));
        })*/
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
const Todo = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.todo.todo_description}</td>
    <td>{props.todo.todo_responsible}</td>
    <td>{props.todo.todo_priority}</td>
    <td>
        <Link to={"/edit/"+props.todo._id}></Link>
    </td>
    <td>
        <Link to={"/delete/"+props.todo._id}></Link>
    </td>
</tr>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class CourseView extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Courses:[]
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:4000/course').then((res)=>{
        this.setState({Courses:res.data});
    })
}

listelements(){
    return this.state.Courses.map((course,i)=>{
        return <Course course = {course} key={i}/>
    })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <table border="2px" align="center" style={{marginTop:100}}>
                <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>PassMark</th>
                <th>Lecturer in charge</th>
                <th>Subjects</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                {this.listelements()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

static TotalCalculation(id){
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/total/'+id).then((res)=>{
        let total = (res.data.total);
        let subCount = (res.data.subjects.length);
        alert('You have to complete '+subCount+" subjects, Which will be Rs."+total+"/= in total.");
    })
}

static buttonClick(Subjects) {
    let data="";
    console.log(Subjects);
    for(let i=0;i<Subjects.length;i++){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:4000/subject/'+Subjects[i]).then((res)=>{
            data = "Name: "+res.data.Name+", Description: "+res.data.Description+", Amount: "+res.data.Amount;
            data = data+'\n';
            alert(data);
        });

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

DBSchema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
Course:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
PassMark:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
},
LecturerInCharge:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
Subjects:{
    type:[mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],

}
});

const SubjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
Description:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
Amount:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
}
});

mongoose.model('Course',CourseSchema);
mongoose.model('Subject',SubjectSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sliit-web',     {useNewUrlParser:true}).then(()=>{
console.log('Connected to DB');
}).catch((err)=>{
   console.error(err);
 });

module.exports = mongoose;

var Express     = require('Express');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var Cors        = require('cors');
var router      = Express.Router();
var UserRoute   = require('./User/user.route');

var app = Express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(Cors());
app.use('/', UserRoute);

app.listen('8081', '127.0.0.1', function(err) {
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(-1);
}
console.log("Server listen on port 8081");
})
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score -1):

```
todoList()
{
    return this.state.todos.map(function(currentTodo,i){
        return <Todo todo={currentTodo} key={i}/>;
    });
}
render()
{
    return(
        <div>
           <h3>Todo List</h3>
           <table>
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Description</th>
                       <th>Responsible</th>
                       <th>Prioroty</th>
                       <th>Completed</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   {this.todoList}
               </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Sebastian Eschweiler check this ones github profile for mern tutorials